# Having problems with Adding multiple labels in a for loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, label

Ok so i've been trying to add like a List of labels to show points in a Yahtzee game.
But im having problems even tho i change the number of players it should add it still won't add another list of them.

http://fuskbugg.se/dl/sN0UMK/yahtzee_help.jpg
(i want another list next to player: 1 2 3 etc.) that is what im trying to accomplish.

Here is my code for the player class

Constructor

```
    public Player(int PlayerID, Form Game)
    {
        id = PlayerID;
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            points[i] = new Label();
            points[i].Text = "_";
            points[i].Location = new Point(112+(id)*30, 80+(i)*29);
            MessageBox.Show((112 + (id) * 28)+"  "+( 80 + (i) * 29) + "");
            Game.Controls.Add(points[i]);
            NotTaken[i] = true;
        }
    }
```

NotTaken is irrelevent.

Game code that adds the amount of players.

```
    public void Start(int Players)
    {
        this.Enabled = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < Players; i++)
        {
            Playerlist.Add(new Player(i, this));
            Label newlbl = new Label();
            this.Controls.Add(newlbl);
            newlbl.Text = (i + 1) + "";
            newlbl.Location = new Point(112 + (i * 28), 56);
        }
    }
```

Any help on this would be very appreciated

Comment: You've not clarified what error your're getting. "it still won't add another list of them" - is not very clear. Any exception stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: http://fuskbugg.se/dl/sN0UMK/yahtzee_help.jpg
That is how its currently adding them i want another list of labels next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this out. Thing was that when i added the labels they were created in the standard size which led to them overlaying each other so i just added 1 line.

```
       points[i].Size = new Size(19, 13);
```